# Search strpos() with a Number Range PHP

Tags: php, iptables, strpos

I want to search a rule, `iptables`, within a string that has a port blocked—and I want to show that port.

For example, the rule `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP;` I'd like to be able to search by `strpos` the string `tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP` but with a range of numbers `1-65335 instead of 8080`.

Please excuse my poor English.

Comment: Use a regex to do this rather than strpos.  If you want more help, include a complete, minimal example.

Comment: @DanFarrell My objective is get the string that has "tcp --dport 1-65355 -j DROP". for example "tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP" or "tcp --dport 21 -j DROP"

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and what happened, and we'll help you figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @DanFarrell i didn't try too much, i used a lot of strpos, but not at this level, so i dont really know what to try. im sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each string is in fixed format like your example, you can search for the number then check if within range using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function

```
$str = 'iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP;';

preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $match); // search for matches
if ($match[0] >= 1 && $match[0] <= 65335) {
    echo "Valid number found on string";
}
```

Pattern `/\d+/` searches for any digit, 1 to unlimited times

**Notes:**

1. Will cause undefined errors/warnings when no number found on string

2. May become inaccurate when more than 1 whole number found

Comment: and how can i get a var with the number ?